# openssl api funtion reference issue

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, signature, elliptic-curve

I am trying to generate and play around with openssl eliptic curves. running this: from the documentation

```
EC_GROUP *curve;
if(NULL == (curve = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1)))
      handleErrors(); 
EC_KEY *key;
if(NULL == (key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1)))
     handleErrors();
if(1 != EC_KEY_generate_key(key)) handleErrors();
```

with theese includes:

```
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I have looked through the ec.h file and it has the functions I am calling. My error is this:

```
key_gen.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name'
key_gen.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `handleErrors'
key_gen.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name'
key_gen.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `handleErrors'
key_gen.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `EC_KEY_generate_key'
key_gen.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `handleErrors'
```

do I need any more includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link in the OpenSSL crypto library when compiling:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o key_gen key_gen.c -lcrypto
```

Comment: Thank you. The curve and key functions got linked but the handleErrors function calls were still undefined. Do you know what I need to include for those?

Comment: @NoahPerkovich That function is not part of the OpenSSL library.  You'll need to pull that from wherever you got this sample code from.

Comment: I got it from https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography. Is there a better way to call the key generation functions?

Comment: The `handleErrors()` function is supposed to be a hint to "fill your own code in here".

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the handleErrors(); yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).